# How to convert string to var name at function call

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I find myself needing to convert a string var (in JavaScript) to a variable name that is called when getting an element. My spontaneous solution to this was writing:

```
this.name = name;
[...]
this.context.drawImage(imageRepository.(this.name), this.x, this.y);
```

This does not work however, returning "Unexpected token (". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a *property name*, not a variable name. You can use bracketed notation for that:

```
imageRepository[this.name]
```

In JavaScript, you can refer to properties in two ways: Using dot notation and a property name *literal* (`obj.foo`), or using bracketed notation and a property name *string* (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression, including looking up a property on another object (`this.name`).

Comment: Aha, thanks :-) property name, I'll make sure to refer to it properly next time

Answer (score 0):

You need bracket notation in this case.

```
imageRepository[this.name]
```

The bracket notation evaluates the variable and selects the appropriate property.